# GameKit - GameCenter authentication works only on simulator

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

In my cocos2d game app I've implemented the Game Center.
If I launch it on simulator or on my iPhone it works correctly: if I'm not logged it show the authentication window of the Game Center.

The problem is on other iPhone: at launch it doesn't show any window of login, so the user is never logged to Game Center!

My code of intro scene inside init method:

```
GameKitHelper *gkHelper = [GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper];
gkHelper.delegate = self;
[gkHelper authenticateLocalPlayer];
```

and my authenticateLocalPlayer method :

```
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    if (isGameCenterAvailable == NO)
       return;

GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
if (localPlayer.authenticated == NO)
{
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError* error)
     {
         [self setLastError:error];

         if (error == nil)
         {
             [self initMatchInvitationHandler];
             [self reportCachedAchievements];
             [self loadAchievements];
         }
     }];
}
```

}

Comment: Open the Game Center app on the affected phone. Can you log in from there? Just in case the Game Center app doesn't exist, it means the device's iOS version is too old and doesn't support Game Center. Version needs to be iOS 4.1 on iPhone and 4.2 on iPad. Be sure to use two different Game Center accounts if you want to test multiplayer connectivity.

Comment: yes I can login from Game Center app. the iOS version is iOS8

Comment: In that case simply NSLog(@"GC error: %@", error) inside the completion handler. Or just set a breakpoint.

Comment: Oh, GameKitHelper .. is that mine per chance? In that case it hasn't been updated in a long time and I believe the recommended way to perform authentication has changed. Maybe try the example from the Game Center programming guide.

Comment: is the GameKitHelper of 2010 by Steffen Itterheim

Comment: Yup that's mine. :)
You may need to adapt it to the new authentication process as detailed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW19

Comment: but I don't understand why on my iPhone it works correctly and also on simulator....but on other devices not!

Comment: where I can find an updated gamekithelper for iOS7?

Comment: Not sure, Ray Wenderlich made one but no idea whether that's up-to-date with iOS 7/8 requirements. I haven't updated GKH in the past couple years.